# how to use batch file variable outside inner for loop

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am not familiar with batch script variable scoping. But I ran into scoping problem due to my lack of batch script experience.

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b "%FolderLocation%"') do (
set fullpathandfilename=%%i ::
For %%A in ("%fullpathandfilename%") do (
Set File=%%~nxA
echo %%File :: this would work and print out only filename
)
echo %File% ::this will not have filename I extracted above
)
```

So how can i use %%File outside my inner for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, `EnableDelayedExpansion`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b "%FolderLocation%"') do (
For %%A in ("%%~i") do (
Set File=%%~nxA
echo !File!
)
:: This shows how "%" doesn't work but "!" does
Echo ^%File^%: %File%   -   ^!File^!: !File!
)
```

And that should work for you. Just remember to use `!File!` inside a for-loop and `%File%` outside.

Comment: interesting. That works. I first tried it with  setfullpathandfilename=%%i and !File! did not work. Then I tried ur solution that had %%~i which made !File! work. Thanks again.

Comment: By default `%%i` includes the quotation marks which would equate: `""value of i""`. If you use `%%~i` it removes the surrounding quote: `"%%~i"`: `"Value of i"`