# Can i use the loop iterator after the loop?

Tags: batch-file

this code works fine (copies a file with "center" in it to c:\temp:

```
dir %1 |FOR /f "tokens=5" %%G IN ('findstr "Center"') DO (
copy %1\%%G c:\temp\
)
```

but I want to use the %%G var after the loop:

```
echo %%G
```

but then what I see is %%G instead of the file name.
why?

Comment: Probably related: [how to use batch file variable outside inner for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495767/how-to-use-batch-file-variable-outside-inner-for-loop)

Comment: I'm not sure if your pipe can work like this; I'd write it as: `for /F "tokens=5" %%G in ('dir /B "%~1" ^| findstr "Center"') do`...

Comment: Yes, the code in the question is simply broken. BTW `"%~1"` is equivalent to `%1` I think.

Comment: `%1` might or might not contain enclosing doublequotes (depending on how the argument is passed to the script); `%~1` will always remove surrounding doublequotes; so `"%~1"` will always contain surrounding doublequotes but avoids double-doublequotes (opposed to `"%1"`)...

Comment: @aschipfl, yes, that's what I meant, `%1` is okay.

Comment: `%1` could lead to problems if the argument contains whitespaces, where `"%~1"` would not...

Comment: @aschipfl, no, because in that case `%1` preserves the quotes: `test.bat "a b c"` -> `echo %1` -> `"a b c"`.

Comment: Yes, @wOxxOm, that's true; my previous comment was a bit misleading; what I wanted to say is: with `%~1` you have full control of the quotes, as they are removed if present, where `%1` may or may not contain them...

Comment: @aschipfl, my point was for the specific case when the main batch file passes its own first parameter to the child process: there's no need to overcomplicate it so we can simply `call child-process %1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the batch file language is designed this way. Actually there are many languages that don't leak the loop variable outside the scope of the loop (depending on how it was declared).

Use a normal variable inside the loop to store the last value:

```
for %%G in (something) do (
    set "lastLoopValue=%%G"
)
echo %lastLoopValue%
```

BTW the code you've posted can be written in one line without any loops:
 `copy %1\*Center* c:\temp\` if you don't mind the case insensitivity of the wildcard approach.

P.S. Fixed version of your code:

```
@echo off
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir %1 /b ^| findstr "Center"') DO (
    copy "%~1\%%G" c:\temp\
    set "lastLoopValue=%%G"
)
echo %lastLoopValue%
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't work, the output is "echo off" which it means the %lastLoopValue% is empty.

Comment: Well, if you ran the example from the answer then of course the output will be empty because there's no file named `something` on your computer.

Comment: of course not, i used my code and the file is copied (inside the loop) but when it getting out the var is empty.

Comment: @Ariel, please show us how you tried wOxxOm's answer...

Comment: @Ariel, your code is broken, I've added a fixed version in the answer.

Comment: thanks, although i still don't understand why in my code %%G is good for copy but is not good to put a value to another var

Comment: I've tried to figure it out but couldn't as I never would have thought this kind of piping to `for` works. Maybe someone else can answer that.